# Bash scripts with tmux to launch a 4-paned window

Tags: bash, exec, tmux

Can anyone help explain what's going on with `tmux`, `bash`, and `exec`? I'm trying to set up a tmux session with a 4-pane window. Ideally, I want to run a command in 3 of the panes: e.g. a Ruby Thin server and a couple of Ruby daemons. This is what I have so far:

`~/.bin/tmux-foo`:

```
#!/bin/sh

tmux new-session -d -s foo 'exec pfoo "bundle exec thin start"'
tmux rename-window 'Foo'
tmux select-window -t foo:0
tmux split-window -h 'exec pfoo "bundle exec compass watch"'
tmux split-window -v -t 0 'exec pfoo "rake ts:start"'
tmux split-window -v -t 1 'exec pfoo'
tmux -2 attach-session -t foo
```

`~/.bin/pfoo`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/projects/foo
rvm use ree

# here I want to execute command1 2 3 or 4...

exec $SHELL
```

It all works... but when I `ctlr-c` in the first pane that is running the thin server, it stops the thin server and returns to the shell. However, the command is not in the history; i.e. if I hit the up key I don't get the `bundle exec thin start` command... I get some other command from my bash history. I'm wondering if there's any way to arrange these scripts so that I get the commands in the bash history.

Also... I've tried many combinations of `exec`, `exec $SHELL -s ...`, and `exec $SHELL -s ... -I` and I'm not quite sure what is going on...

Can anyone help explain the general idea of what is going on with `tmux` and `bash` and `exec` here?

Comment: For the record, I use https://github.com/jimeh/tmuxifier now (rather than tmuxinator, which has non-shell dependencies).

Answer (score 78, accepted):

As others have mentioned, your commands are being run by the shell script *before* launching your `$SHELL`; there is no general way the instance of `$SHELL` can know what its parent ran before starting it.

To get the “initial command” into the shell history, you need to feed the command keystrokes directly to the instance of `$SHELL` itself (after it has been started, of course). In other contexts I might suggest using a small Expect program to spawn an instance of `$SHELL`, feed it the keystrokes, then use `interact` to tie the tty to the *expect*-spawned `$SHELL`.

But in the context of *tmux*, we can just use `send-keys`:

```
#!/bin/sh

tmux new-session -d -s foo 'exec pfoo'
tmux send-keys 'bundle exec thin start' 'C-m'
tmux rename-window 'Foo'
tmux select-window -t foo:0
tmux split-window -h 'exec pfoo'
tmux send-keys 'bundle exec compass watch' 'C-m'
tmux split-window -v -t 0 'exec pfoo'
tmux send-keys 'rake ts:start' 'C-m'
tmux split-window -v -t 1 'exec pfoo'
tmux -2 attach-session -t foo
```

Comment: May I ask, what is `'exec pfoo'` supposed to do? I tried running the line on my instance but it's not creating the session (it seems to be exiting right after trying to create a session and then adds a number of characters). Wonder if it could be related to my PuTTy settings.

Comment: `'exec pfoo'` is a placeholder here for whatever command you actually want to execute.

Comment: `'exec pfoo'` is executing one of your `pfoo` scripts, saved inside one of your `$PATH` directories.

Answer (score 21):

[tmuxinator](https://github.com/aziz/tmuxinator) lets you specify this with a nice yaml file. For your case you could have:

```
# ~/.tmuxinator/foo.yml
# you can make as many tabs as you wish...

project_name: foo
project_root: ~/projects/foo
rvm: ree
tabs:
  - main:
      layout: tiled
      panes:
        - bundle exec thin start
        - bundle exec compass watch
        - #empty, will just run plain bash
        - rake ts:start
```

You can of course have extra windows etc.

Comment: So good to know about tmuxinator, thanks for this !

Comment: 10 years later and tmuxinator is still my preferred answer. Super easy to start/stop running a project that needs multiple terminals with one command.

Comment: Nice, but how about a linux version?

Comment: @Erica - tmuxinator is cross platform.  There is a debian/ubuntu package, it's available from homebrew/linuxbrew, or see the github page for other ways to install it.

Answer (score 7):

Place the following into the command prompt [all as one line], it will open 4 tmux panels automatically (I know this wasn't the question, but this looks somewhat easier than what I saw posted):

```
    tmux new-session \; \split-window -v \; \split-window -h \; \select-pane -t 0 \; \split-window -h
```

Now you can take that command and use it with whatever scripting language you like [you need to double the escape characters {backslash characters} if using perl...and probably other languages].

This runs the subsequent command in the newer tmux panel, reverting to the first and splitting it at the end.

Answer (score 3):

You are running the command and then entering the interactive shell; the command run from the script, not being in an interactive shell, doesn't get recorded in the history.  You really want a way to stuff (that's a technical term :) once upon a time it was `TIOCSTI` for "terminal ioctl(): stuff input") input for the shell into the window.

With `tmux`, it looks like you use buffers for this.  Something along the lines of (untested)

```
#! /bin/bash
cd ~/projects/foo
rvm use ree

if [[ $# != 0 ]]; then
  tmux set-buffer "$(printf '%s\n' "$*")" \; paste-buffer -d
fi

exec ${SHELL:-/bin/sh}
```

Comment: Hmm interesting... it doesn't quite work, but I see what you mean. I'll try to play around with the idea. Thank you!

Comment: In (newer?) ksh, there is a environment variable setting, its one of the HIST* vars, and if you set it the right way, it will capture alias and function definitions executed from the .profile files into the current (non-interactive) shell's history. As both new ksh and bash are Posix compliant, it's highly likely that bash can do this too.  (Sorry, its a long story about why I can't dig out and give you the exact syntax about how to do this ;-( )

Answer (score 3):

You can create a bash script like this.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

tmux new-session -d -s mysession
tmux send-keys -t mysession "cd ~" Enter
tmux split-window -h -t mysession
tmux send-keys -t mysession "watch -n 1 df -H" Enter
tmux split-window -v -p 50 -t mysession
tmux send-keys -t mysession "htop" Enter
tmux select-pane -t mysession:0.0
tmux split-window -v -p 50 -t mysession
tmux send-keys -t mysession "cd ~" Enter
tmux select-pane -t mysession:0.0
# Attach to session 
tmux attach -t mysession
```

You can change commands inside `""` in each `send-keys` command as per your preference.

Comment: Pretty helpful example, if it helps, the order of the panes are: 1st command: top left. 2nd command: top right. 3rd command: bottom right. 4th command: bottom left