# Using a bash script to launch screen, then split and resize a screen

Tags: bash, scripting, terminal

I'm trying to build a bash script to launch a screen session, split the screen and then resize one of the screens.  Below is what I run manually from the terminal.

```
$screen
$ cd /some/directory
```

<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> then <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> //splits the screen in two

<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> //navigate to the "new" screen

<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> //create another terminal

<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> :resize -15 //resize the screen

```
$cd /another/dictionary
```

<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> //navigate to the first screen

```
$clear
```

I've done some bash scripting but nothing with keystrokes.  I've been trying to find something to send <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> within a bash script but I'm not sure if I can or if after I launch screen if I can interact with screen that way.  I haven't been able to find anything in my googling yet.  Any help or direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: IMHO its not possible to interactively script screen. Have you looked at tmux? -> [tmux scripting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447278/bash-scripts-with-tmux-to-launch-a-4-paned-window)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is old but I needed this, too, and could not find an answer. I finally solved it out like this:

- make a configuration file, say **.splitscreenrc**:

  ```
  chdir /etc
  screen 0
  stuff "ls -1\n"
  split
  focus down
  resize 3
  chdir /tmp
  screen 1
  stuff "ls\n"
  focus up
  ```
- run `screen -c .splitscreenrc`

Hope this helps someone ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using `expect`:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set prompt {\$ }   ;# this is a regular expression to match your shell prompt
set dir1 /tmp
set dir2 /var/log

spawn screen
expect -re $prompt
send -- "\001S"
expect -re $prompt
send -- "cd $dir1\r"
expect -re $prompt
send -- "\001\t"
send -- "\001c"
expect -re $prompt
send -- "\001:resize -15\r"
send -- "cd $dir2\r"
expect -re $prompt
send -- "\001\t"
send -- "clear\r"

interact
```