# Bash script for tmux managing

Tags: bash, scripting, automation, tmux

I'd like to start `tmux` from terminal, split it window and execute in the splits some commands. Furthermore, I'd like to did with bash script, that I start from terminal. Now, I've been able to start `tmux` only.

```
#!/bin/sh

tmux

# How to split tmux window there, and start commands in splits?
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash scripts with tmux to launch a 4-paned window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447278/bash-scripts-with-tmux-to-launch-a-4-paned-window)

Comment: I wrote a tool **retmux** https://github.com/sk1418/retmux it can restore your tmux sessions/layouts/path in window/even text on screen easily. just `retmux -r`  but executing command is not supported. You may want to take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a script started `tmux`, splitted for to panes and started `ls` in the left pane and `top` in the right one.

```
#!/bin/sh

tmux new-session -d -s main ;
tmux split-window -h ;
tmux select-pane -L
tmux send-keys -t main 'ls' C-m
tmux select-pane -R
tmux send-keys -t main 'top' C-m
tmux attach-session -d -t main
```